# Mongoose check if email and channel name exist (Two different collections) then save with reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is there a better solution to check two collections and then save one with reference, but if something goes wrong delete the one you already created.

In this code, I want to check if an email in the collection exists and a channel name in another. Next, save a user account and then create a user channel with reference to a user account but if something happens, delete a user account and return an error to the client.

```
let error = {}
await userSchema.findOne({email:body.email},(err, doc) => 
{ 
  if(err){
    return console.log(err)
  }
  if(doc){
    error.email = `Email ${data.email} already used!`
  }
})

await channelSchema.findOne({channelname:body.channelname},(err, doc) => 
{ 
  if(err){
    return console.log(err)
  }
  if(doc){
    error.channelname = `Channel name ${data.channelname} already used!`
  }
})
if(error !== {}) {
 return res.status(400).json(error)
}else{
  const newUser = new userSchema({
    email:body.email,
    password: data.password
  })
  const newProfile = new channelSchema({
    owner:newUser.id,
    channelname: body.channelname
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `.then .catch` with await together, so use `async/await` with `try/cathc` do like this:

```
try {
  let error = {};
  let user = await userSchema.findOne({ email: body.email });
  if (user) {
    error.email = `Email ${data.email} already used!`;
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
  let channel = await channelSchema.findOne({ channelname: body.channelname });
  if (channel) {
    error.channelname = `Channel name ${data.channelname} already used!`;
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
  const newUser = new userSchema({
    email: body.email,
    password: data.password,
  });
  const newProfile = new channelSchema({
    owner: newUser.id,
    channelname: body.channelname,
  });
} catch (error) {
  return console.log(err);
}
```